# Convert list of datetime() and other types into string

Tags: python, list, datetime

In python, how would we convert this list so that the datetimes are converted to strings:

```
list = [
    datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31, 0, 0),
    "some string",
    datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 20, 1, 0),
    "another string"]
```

wanted output:

```
["2020-12-31 00:00", "some string", "2014-11-20: 01:00", "another string"]
```

Comment: Please, edit your question so problem becomes more certain. Explain what you want as desired result. What did you try so far? What problems did you met?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I closed your question under an existing one that covers how to convert anything to string, but if that doesn't answer your question, for example if you don't know how to loop over the list, you can [edit] to clarify, and please mention what you've already tried.

Comment: `2014-11-20:` seems to have an extra colon

Answer (score 1):

First, careful using `list` as a variable name, it will [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the built-in name for the datatype.

To convert the list to all strings, try:

```
x = [str(item) for item in x]
```

where `x` is the variable name of the list.